# how to match an input to a item in a list within a while loop - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop

I am struggling to understand why when i input the players choice it keep looping even if they type the right warrior type. would be most grateful if anyone can help.

```
playerchoice = ""

confirmwarrior = ""

warriortype = ("swordsman", "wizard", "archer", "healer")

while playerselection != warriortype:

        playerselection = input("""

        please select the type of warrior you wish to be:

        - Swordsman
        - Wizard
        - Archer
        - Healer

        """).lower()
else:
    print("you have entered and incorrect Warrior, please try again")    

print("your chosen Warrior is",playerselection)

    while confirmwarrior != "y":

        confirmwarrior = input("""

        are you happy with this Warrior?
        stefan

        y - yes
        N - No

        """)
        confirmwarrior.lower()


print("you have Chosen to be", playerselection)
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? It's kinda confusing

Comment: Also, your `while playerselection != warriortype:` will return an error because you haven't declared the variable `playerselection`

Comment: is that ok i approve the changes.

Comment: I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings on how while-else-loops work in Python. Try looking that up and that may answer some questions.

Comment: say, you meant `playerchoice` in the while loop, you have to use `not in` operation instead of `!=`, because you want to check the user input is one of the strings in the tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the modified code that works properly:

```
playerchoice = ""
playerselection = '' # set the variable playerselection to an empty string before the while loop
confirmwarrior = ""

warriortype = ("swordsman", "wizard", "archer", "healer")

while not playerselection in warriortype: # This is where you're missing

        playerselection = input("""

        please select the type of warrior you wish to be:

        - Swordsman
        - Wizard
        - Archer
        - Healer

        """).lower()
else:
    print("you have entered and incorrect Warrior, please try again")    

    print("your chosen Warrior is",playerselection) # Fixed your indentation here

    while confirmwarrior != "y":

        confirmwarrior = input("""

        are you happy with this Warrior?
        stefan

        y - yes
        N - No

        """)
        confirmwarrior.lower()


print("you have Chosen to be", playerselection)
```

EDIT: Here's the code that re-asks you what type of warrior you want to be when you answered no after choosing a warrior:

```
playerchoice = ""
playerselection = ''
confirmwarrior = ""

warriortype = ("swordsman", "wizard", "archer", "healer")

while confirmwarrior != "y":

    playerselection = input("""

    please select the type of warrior you wish to be:

    - Swordsman
    - Wizard
    - Archer
    - Healer

    """).lower()

    if not playerselection in warriortype:
        print("you have entered and incorrect Warrior, please try again")
        continue

    print("your chosen Warrior is", playerselection)


    confirmwarrior = input("""

    are you happy with this Warrior?
    stefan

    y - yes
    N - No

    """)
    confirmwarrior.lower()


print("you have Chosen to be", playerselection)
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help the first part has fixed the problem with while not ...in. the second part are you happy with this warrior. when i type no it seems to go into a loop without going back to entering the choice again. do you know if there is a way to get the while loop to go back to the first to type the warrior again. thank you

Comment: @StefanTrinh Hello, I've edited my answer to the working version, hope this helps!

Comment: thanks appreciate it, i understand where i was going wrong now.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is going on is your while condition

You are comparing the string entered by the user as input which will always be one string such as "swordsman" and comparing to see if it is not equal with a tuple containing multiple strings which will always be true.

I think the condition you are looking for would be

```
while playerselection not in warriortype:
```

which will become false when playerselection is equal to one of the items in your tuple.

Comment: I don't think a statement like `a not in b` is valid, you can do `not a in b` instead

Comment: ```>>> a = ("hello", "hi")
>>> "foo" not in a
True```

Works just fine for me

Comment: Oh, *facepalm* I forget about that. Thanks.